# How to calculate the division and remainder of a big number manually

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $x = 2017^{2017}$. How can I manually determine:

1. The remainder of the division of $x$ by $31$
2. The least significant digit of $x$

Comment: Your title does not match with the body. Namely, the title mentions calculating the division (I assume you mean quotient), but the body does not require the quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FIRST QUESTION

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
2017^{2017} &=& 2017^{30\times67+7} \\
&=& \left(2017^{30}\right)^{67} \times 2017^7 \\
&\equiv& 1^{67} \times 2^7 & \pmod {31} \\
&=& 128 \\
&\equiv& 4 & \pmod {31}
\end{array}$$

Note that $2017^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod{31}$ is Fermat's little theorem.

### SECOND QUESTION

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
2017^{2017} &=& 2017^{4\times504+1} \\
&=& \left(2017^{4}\right)^{504} \times 2017 \\
&\equiv& 1^{504} \times 7 & \pmod {10} \\
&=& 7 \\
\end{array}$$

Note that $2017^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ is Euler's totient theorem.

Comment: Why $2017^{{30}^{67}} \times 2017^7 \equiv 1^{67} \times 2^7 \pmod {31}$?

Comment: Because $2017^{30}\equiv1\pmod{31}$ and $2017\equiv 2\pmod{31}$.