# Calculate least significant digit of large number with exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $x = 2017^{2017}$

How can I determine the least significant digit of $x$?

Can this be solved without using the Euler's totient theorem?

Comment: Could you give us some context for this question?  For instance: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How did this question come up; is it from a class, a textbook, or contest?  Have you learned anything about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)?

Comment: This is a class question. This problem came amidst of other exercises involving congruences and fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Also, you've already received and answer to [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2267991/81360).  It would be helpful if you could tell us what exactly you would like clarified or explained more thoroughly.

Comment: I don't understand the step-by-step resolution (namely the usage of 2017 = 4*504+1) and think that I should use an alternative process to the Euler's totient theorem.

Comment: Even without the theorem, you can verify that $2017^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ by looking at the least significant digit of $7^1,7^2,7^3,7^4$